# Are questions about xkcd explanations allowed here?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is an [xkcd](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xkcd) tag in scifi stackexchange with only 9 questions

Going through them, all the questions tagged with [xkcd](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xkcd) are about specific comics which are written around a known work of scifi and/or fantasy

But if there are comics that I don't understand, is it allowed to ask for an explanation of such comics here? Suppose a comic is clearly not about physics/astronomy/real science of any kind, but it is not clear what the comic is about either. Can I use the [xkcd](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xkcd) tag for an explanation of such comics here?

Comment: Related: [Is tag:xkcd going to be contentious?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7906/23386)

Comment: I don't understand the down votes on a question seeking clarification of scope.

Comment: @SQB - possibly, because people see (correctly or not) a question worded as "are XYZ allowed" as a positive proposal to disallow XYZ; and downvote in sign of disagreement because they want to keep XYZ.

Comment: @dvk they should learn to read the whole question first then

Comment: @user13267 - fact of life. People don't read.

Answer (score 6):

As long as it's clear that the aspect of the comic you're asking about is in some way related to science fiction or fantasy, and not romance, sarcasm, [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/), or [language](https://english.stackexchange.com/), I don't see why not.

If you look through the questions tagged [xkcd](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xkcd), you can see a proud history of such questions:

- [Who are Darmok and Jalad and what is Kalenda's?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3744/31051) has 24 upvotes and 4 downvotes
- [Why is Arwen dying?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40031/31051) has 33 upvotes and 4 downvotes

Although these are fairly old questions (the most recent is from 2013), they're certainly not off-topic.

There needn't be any *recognizable* SFF work behind the comic for a question about it to be on-topic; I would liken those cases to our story-ID questions, which are contentious but largely accepted. As long as there are identifiable SFF elements (or good reason to believe there's an SFF inspiration), I don't see why such a question would be off-topic.

I would, however, caution you to do some basic research before asking your question. Lack of research effort is a common downvote reason, and the logic behind any XKCD joke can usually be easily identified by Googling some key words from the comic (the first question I linked to above is [a great example](https://www.google.ca/search?q=darmok+jalad+kalendas&oq=darmok+jalad+kalendas)).

If there's no clear SFFnal connection in the comic (as in [the example](https://xkcd.com/8/) posted in the comments), that would be off-topic. Such a question *might* be on-topic at the [proposed comics.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94426/comics-cartoons-animation) (if that ever happens), but in the meantime would be better-served [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).

Comment: Those questions are about xkcd comics clearly centered around scifi/fantasy (question 1 has an alien looking character in the comic, question 2 has an LotR reference). I am talking about the validity of  cases where I am not sure what the question is about, and possibly the comic is not about a scifi work (but definitely not about math or science either)

Comment: @user13267 Do you have an example?

Comment: @user13267 Seems totally off-topic then. Otherwise you could ask about any property under the premise that there might be some unknown speculative fiction layer behind it.

Comment: May be some old ones like this? https://xkcd.com/8/

Comment: @user13267 That one I'd say no; I'm going to refer to our story-id policy, which is that a question must have identifiable SFFnal elements (or good reason to believe there's an SFF inspiration). Chat would be a better place for the more general questions

Comment: ExplainXKCD.com has a lot of information too.

Comment: @JasonBaker while I agree with your criteria, I disagree with your evaluation: red robot-like spiders climbing free-floating cubes seems quite SFFnal to me — not referencing anything SFFnal, but SFFnal itself.